# How do you increase your snakpack capacity?

Tags: bugsnax

The game essentially asks you to catch several Bugsnax but the inventory is really small, and there's apparently no shop in this game.
How do you increase your snakpack capacity? I know it's possible, there's clearly more space which is initially locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find **Gramble** (Filbo will eventually give you the mission) which is located in Simmering Springs.
Once you help him to catch his little friends he will join Snaxburg and start a sort of farm. He will asks you to donate more friends to his collection, and as a reward you will get more Snaxbugs space in your inventory.